# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Adapter invocation failing in iOS 5 after upgrading to v6.1

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

We have developed a Worklight-based Hybrid application with Native pages as well. Our start page is a native page from which we are invoking an adapter.

After upgrading to Worklight 6.1, this adapter invocation is now always failing in iOS 5, however continues to function correctly in iOS 6 and iOS 7.

When the adapter invocation fails, it returns raw HTML as the response: [Adapter Failure Response](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68580104/test.html).

In Xcode Console this is the error we see:

> [ERROR] Worklight: -[WLRequest requestFailed:]:338::Status code='404'
>   error='(null)' [ERROR] Worklight: -[WLClient
>   onInvokeProcedureFailure:userInfo:]:696::response string=[HTML
>   returning from adapter](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68580104/test.html)

The same application in Worklight 6.0.0.x works OK in iOS 5, 6 and 7.

[This sample application](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68580104/TESTPROJ.zip) can be used to see the error.

Comment: A very confusing question. You say "crash", "adapter not working", "ios5 6 7". Edit the question and be much more detailed in what you are experiencing.

Comment: What is the confusing thing in this....I am asking if i call adapter from native as per the worklight docs it is working fine in `ios 6` and `ios 7`. Why this is not working in `ios 5` if i am running the same code and why adapter call is returning html instead of some success or failure response. Why you guys are closing this question too fast. Is this the bug in worklight 6.1.

Comment: i have edited the question , these are the logs displaying on xcode console while hitting adapter on `ios 5`

Comment: I have given the reply to your question, Please check @IdanAdar

Comment: Thanks. I am uncertain about it. I have forwarded it to others to take a look.

Comment: How much time it will take to resolve , because from our side we confirm that it is not working in `ios 5`. We tried it with fresh project in 6.1 working version and tried to connect worklight and calling adapter. It is giving the same thing as we already discussed. I am giving you the sample project which we have tested here so please look into it and update us. I have updated my question where you can find link for sample project.

Comment: I don't have estimates; if you are an IBM customer you can open a PMR.

Comment: This is now being investigated. Thanks!

Comment: please either you (as the IBM Business Partner) or the customer open a PMR so an iFix release could be delivered to you.

Comment: did you open a PMR yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From tests made, it appears that the adapter invocation fails only in iOS 5 because the request sent contains double-slashes whereas in iOS 6 and 7 it contains one slash.

This can be verified in Wireshark:

[image]

- This is a defect
- There is not applicable workaround

Once the defect is fixed, it will be available via [IBM Fix Central](https://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/), as well as in the PMR that your customer needs to open anyway to get this fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Check your wlclient.properties file, especially wlServerContext property. Looks like you're trying to connect to invalid URL.

Comment: Why the same app is working on othe IOS version (6 and 7) if this is the case